# Why do we use Disassociate action in AccountController?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

This code was Auto- generated by Visual studio

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Disassociate(string provider, string providerUserId)
    {
        string ownerAccount = OAuthWebSecurity.GetUserName(provider, providerUserId);
        ManageMessageId? message = null;

        // Only disassociate the account if the currently logged in user is the owner
        if (ownerAccount == User.Identity.Name)
        {
            // Use a transaction to prevent the user from deleting their last login credential
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable }))
            {
                bool hasLocalAccount = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
                if (hasLocalAccount || OAuthWebSecurity.GetAccountsFromUserName(User.Identity.Name).Count > 1)
                {
                    OAuthWebSecurity.DeleteAccount(provider, providerUserId);
                    scope.Complete();
                    message = ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess;
                }
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = message });
    }
```

Why do we use Disassociate action in AccountController of Mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Disassociate action is used for removing a linked account (Google, Facebook, Microsoft, etc) from a user.

In the default MVC5 AccountController, its only usage is on the Manage Accounts page where it only shows up if the user has a local password or if the user has more than one linked account.